# Doxygen : how to process anonymous member in compound

Tags: c++, class, doxygen

> my c++ code as below, and I want to use Doxygen produce xml file.

```
// c++ code
struct TestStru
{
    struct{
        int a;
    } m_stru;
    union{
        int b;
        char c;
    } m_union;
    int d;
};
```

> The real output xml as follows, I omitted some information not important. My question is how to distinguish members in anonymous struct or union like 'a' from xml, or how could I configure Doxygen to achieve this.

```
<memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_test_stru_1a898ff9a1bccfc215accd3da2db864509" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
  <type>int</type>
  <definition>int TestStru::a</definition>
  <argsstring></argsstring>
  <name>a</name>
</memberdef>
<memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_test_stru_1aeca04a3d70feb1cef125df66625487ef" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
  <type>struct TestStru::@0</type>
  <definition>struct TestStru::@0  TestStru::m_stru</definition>
  <argsstring></argsstring>
  <name>m_stru</name>
</memberdef>
<memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_test_stru_1a2831fb7fc8f16abb913fe9a3c1fae19a" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
  <type>int</type>
  <definition>int TestStru::b</definition>
  <argsstring></argsstring>
  <name>b</name>
</memberdef>
<memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_test_stru_1aaa51d26f2195dcfdb0ce8f500275221b" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
  <type>char</type>
  <definition>char TestStru::c</definition>
  <argsstring></argsstring>
  <name>c</name>
</memberdef>
<memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_test_stru_1a547ce77ff0347d5a14ac43e078964022" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
  <type>union TestStru::@1</type>
  <definition>union TestStru::@1  TestStru::m_union</definition>
</memberdef>
<memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_test_stru_1a5437512aa23a668c8e10865521c35f7c" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
  <type>int</type>
  <definition>int TestStru::d</definition>
  <argsstring></argsstring>
  <name>d</name>
</memberdef>
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. In the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues) there are a few issues recorded regarding the use of anonymous enums / structs / unions. The anonymous parts are in your example denoted by `@...`, when setting up in the code a non-anonymous name it should work.